# Website Image from Google Drive Not Updating

Tags: javascript, html, image, caching, google-drive-api

I am working on a landslide monitoring and forecast network website and we have maps displayed on it. The website was built on Google Sites and it fetches the images with embedded code that calls the files from a Google Drive folder.

Every five minutes, the images are updated on that Google Drive folder and should be reflected on the site, but they aren't. The user only sees the first image loaded and only when they click on the image and see it through the Google Drive folder do they see the updated image.

I've seen other similar questions around and I have tried modifying the URL with the current time using JavaScript to try and cache a new version of the image, but the image doesn't update on the site. What could be the cause of this?

## Code for **updating the URL**:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var d = new Date(); 
    document.getElementById("map").src = 
      "https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=10BZXwdNxL7iOMbNGI59Wtvxgk3bd-upr&export=view&sz=w5000&ver=" +
       d.getTime();
console.log(document.getElementById("map").src)
</script>
```

## This is the **code for the embedded image on Google Sites**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Google Drive</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=10BZXwdNxL7iOMbNGI59Wtvxgk3bd-upr&export=view">
    <img id="map" style= 'max-inline-size: 100%;block-size: 100%;'
        src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=10BZXwdNxL7iOMbNGI59Wtvxgk3bd-upr&export=view&sz=w5000" alt="Page Image">
    <br>
    </a>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var d = new Date(); 
    document.getElementById("map").src = 
      "https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=10BZXwdNxL7iOMbNGI59Wtvxgk3bd-upr&export=view&sz=w5000&ver=" +
       d.getTime();
console.log(document.getElementById("map").src)
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Google drive is not a file hosting platform they are going to block you if you download the same file more then X number of times in a day.  Host it.

Comment: Hi. The images are accessed through the embedded code feature on Google Sites. Does that count as downloading it? The website has been up for months and we haven't had an issue related to accessing the images, only keeping them updated on the site when they are updated on the Drive folder. Also, could hosting the files somewhere else solve the issue first described?

Comment: It would be a good idea to store the images in `AWS S3` for your usecase. It will be dirt cheap to store there until you have tons of GB data. Here is more info: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

Comment: Yes it counts if your accessing it your downloading it into memory of the server thats accessing it and then hosting it to you.  Web programing 101

Comment: @Chinz thanks for the suggestion! I'll ask my supervisor if that's something they are open to do. However, I do have to ask again: will this lead to solving the main issue?

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo Thanks for the 101 lesson I'm a geology student, so this is pretty new to me :) So let's say I host it somewhere else, could this solve the main issue or is this a caching problem with the browser?

Comment: Yes it will welcome to programming 